# calling member in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate the receipt using the Pandas framework based on a given menu. How can I accomplish the following task: find the word "luxury" in the menu, and if found, add the preceding item to a new list called "receipt"? Here is the menu:
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRMHQ.png)

To be honest, I haven't accomplished anything positive to share with you at the moment. However, if anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I have been searching for an answer for over a week now

Comment: Please provide a reproducible object (**as code**) for your pandas DataFrame, it's otherwise ambiguous and non reproducible. It however looks like you're importing your data incorrectly, you should have several columns, not just **one**

Comment: What's your expected result ?

Comment: I'm working with a menu in my code, and I want to implement a condition where if the received value is equal to 'luxury', for instance, the code will calculate the sum of the pervious member witch is the price

Answer (score 0):

As the people in the comments have pointed out, you're far more likely to get help if you make it easy for people to help you. I.e. Instead of supplying an image of your data example, supply it in code like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'name': ['borek', 'pizza', 'spring roll', 'cheese cake', 'pudding', 'caramel cake', 'orange', 'lemon', 'cherry'],
    'type': ['luxury', 'normal', 'economy', 'normal', 'economy', 'luxury', 'normal', 'economy', 'luxury'],
    'price': [3000, 2500, 2200, 1700, 1600, 2000, 1100, 1300, 1500],
    'ma': ['fingerfood', 'fingerfood', 'fingerfood', 'dessert', 'dessert', 'dessert', 'drink', 'drink', 'drink']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, if I understand what you want to do, you can subset the df to only include rows where "luxury" is present in the "type" column, and then convert the items in the *preceding* column (i.e. the name column) to a list variable called receipt? If so, the code below should do the trick:

```
df_subset = df.loc[df['type'] == 'luxury'] #Subset data to rows that have luxury in "type"column
receipt = df_subset["name"].to_list() #Put values in the names column into a list variable called receipt.
```

If you want a one-liner, this is the two commands combined:

```
receipt = (df.loc[df['type'] == 'luxury'])["name"].to_list()
```

I ran it in Jupyter and this is what you get:
[image]

However, I then saw your comment about getting the sum of prices of the "previous member" which, while unclear suggests that you want a sum of all items which are categorized as luxury. In that case, you can use a similar approach of subsetting the data, and the summing the price values into a variable called receipts:

df_subset = df.loc[df['type'] == 'luxury']
receipt = df_subset["price"].sum()

[image]